# How to proof the number of possible functions?

Tags: haskell

Looking at function declaration, for example:

```
myFoo :: Bool -> Bool
```

I could say, the function `myFoo` has four possible unique implementation because function type is the exponent operator, here is the proof from the case above `2^2 = 4`:

```
myFoo1 :: Bool -> Bool
myFoo1 True = False 
myFoo1 True = True


myFoo2 :: Bool -> Bool
myFoo2 False = False 
myFoo2 False = True
```

How I have following data declaration:

```
data Quad =
  One
  | Two
  | Three
  | Four
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and following function:

```
funcQuad :: Quad -> Quad
```

possible implementations are `256(4^4)`. I can not image it, there are a lot of implementation.

How can I proof without writing it out?

Comment: What do you want to proof? That 4^4 is 256? It's just simple combinatoric fact that follows from the nature of algebraic data types. And you always can write program that generates all possible functions.

Comment: You say there are 4 functions of type `Bool -> Bool` but you only list two -
 you are missing `id` and `not`

Comment: @user2407038 Actually all four are missing, because neither of the two functions defined is a total function of type `Bool -> Bool`; rather, they are both definitions with overlapping, incomplete patterns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use algebra to count the number of inhabitant of a type.

There are 3 main type constructions:

- The sum type: `Either a b`, written as a + b
- The product type: `(a, b)`, written as a × b
- The exponent (arrow) type, `a -> b`, written as b<sup>a</sup>

There are also some basic types such as the unit type `()`, written as `1`, and the empty type `Void`, written as `0`.

Most of the common algebra work on types (distribution, commutativity, powers, etc...). The underlying meaning of the resulting expression is the number of inhabitants of your type. Equality can be translated as isomorphisms in the type world.

For an enumeration (i.e. the union of nullary constructors) like yours, we usually write that as `1 + 1 + ... + 1` with `n` `1`s, given `n` the number of constructors.

Here, your `Quad` type translates as `1 + 1 + 1 + 1` in types, and that can be reduced as `4`. Then, your `Quad -> Quad` type is written as 4<sup>4</sup>, which is 256.

Comment: I thought "algebraic data type" was because they are initial algebras.

Comment: Can you please explain what is a isomorphism?

Comment: An isomorphism is just a fancy word for equivalence. An isomorphism between X and Y means that there is a one-to-one correspondance between every element from X and Y.

Answer (score 3):

A function *f : A → B* maps values *x ↦ f(x)*. Given *A* and *B* are **finite** sets, than the number of possible functions, is limited to *|B| <sup>|A|</sup>*.

We can proof this by simple combinatorics. For every *x ∈ A*, there are *|B|* possible values to map *f(x)* to. For every such *x* we can independently pick a value *b ∈ B*, so as a result the total number of possible values is *|B| × |B| × ...  × |B| = |B| <sup>|A|</sup>*.

For the `Quad` type, if you construct a function `f :: Quad -> Quad`, the *A = B = `Quad`*. That means that *|A| = |B| = 4* (since there are four possible values, and none have parameters). So that means there are *4<sup>4</sup>=256* possibilities.

The number of fuctions `g :: Quad -> Bool` is thus 16: since *A = `Quad`* and *B = `Bool`*, this means that *|A| = 4* and *|B| = 2*, so the number of possible functions is 2<sup>4</sup>=16. These are the following:

```
g01 One   = False
g01 Two   = False
g01 Three = False
g01 Four  = False

g02 One   = False
g02 Two   = False
g02 Three = False
g02 Four  = True

g03 One   = False
g03 Two   = False
g03 Three = True
g03 Four  = False

g04 One   = False
g04 Two   = False
g04 Three = True
g04 Four  = True

g05 One   = False
g05 Two   = True
g05 Three = False
g05 Four  = False

g06 One   = False
g06 Two   = True
g06 Three = False
g06 Four  = True

g07 One   = False
g07 Two   = True
g07 Three = True
g07 Four  = False

g08 One   = False
g08 Two   = True
g08 Three = True
g08 Four  = True

g09 One   = True
g09 Two   = False
g09 Three = False
g09 Four  = False

g10 One   = True
g10 Two   = False
g10 Three = False
g10 Four  = True

g11 One   = True
g11 Two   = False
g11 Three = True
g11 Four  = False

g12 One   = True
g12 Two   = False
g12 Three = True
g12 Four  = True

g13 One   = True
g13 Two   = True
g13 Three = False
g13 Four  = False

g14 One   = True
g14 Two   = True
g14 Three = False
g14 Four  = True

g15 One   = True
g15 Two   = True
g15 Three = True
g15 Four  = False

g16 One   = True
g16 Two   = True
g16 Three = True
g16 Four  = True
```

Finally one can ask about the number of functions `f :: a -> b -> c`. `a -> b -> c` is short for `a -> (b -> c)`. So the number of functions `f :: Quad -> (Quad -> Bool)`. Since the number of function `Quad -> Bool` is 16, this thus means that *A = `Quad`* and *B = `(Quad -> Bool)`* and thus *|A| = 4* and *|B| = 16*. This results in a total of *16<sup>4</sup>=65 536* possible functions. Since the number of possible implementations increases very fast, exhaustively enumerating them will thus easily become unfeasible.

Answer (score 3):

You agree that `Quad` = 4 and `Quad -> Quad` = 4<sup>4</sup>. So let’s do a little algebra to convince ourselves that there are 256 possible implementations of a function of type `Quad -> Quad`.

4<sup>4</sup> = 4 × 4 × 4 × 4. In types, that would be `(Quad, Quad, Quad, Quad)`. And we can explicitly write out that isomorphism as a pair of Haskell functions:

```
type Quad4 = (Quad, Quad, Quad, Quad)

tupleToFunction :: Quad4 -> (Quad -> Quad)
tupleToFunction (a, b, c, d) x = case x of
  One -> a
  Two -> b
  Three -> c
  Four -> d

functionToTuple :: (Quad -> Quad) -> Quad4
functionToTuple f = (f One, f Two, f Three, f Four)
```

Now, here’s the trick: you can think of `Quad4` as a 4-digit number in base 4, ranging from 0000<sub>4</sub> = 0 = `(One, One, One, One)` to 3333<sub>4</sub> = 255 = `(Four, Four, Four, Four)`.

Each one of these numbers represents a possible implementation. We can convert a number to an implementation by just selecting a digit and using it as the output; and we can convert an implementation to a number by “packing” all its possible outputs into the digits of a number. So there’s also an isomorphism between `Quad -> Quad` and `Word8`!

You could also do this by expanding the product type (tuple) into sum types (`Either`). For `Quad` it would be huge, but here’s how you’d do it with `Bool -> Bool` = 2<sup>2</sup> = 2 × 2 = 2 + 2:

```
type BB = Either Bool Bool

eitherToFunction :: BB -> (Bool -> Bool)
eitherToFunction (Left a) _ = a
eitherToFunction (Right a) b = a == b  -- xnor
```

Now we can represent `const True` as `Left True`, `const False` as `Left False`, `id` as `Right True`, and `not` as `Right False`, and we write the other half of the isomorphism accordingly:

```
functionToEither :: (Bool -> Bool) -> BB
functionToEither f
  | f True && f False = Left True
  | f True = Right True
  | f False = Right False
  | otherwise = Left False
```